# Glyphicon change color when hover a

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

How can i make it work so that when i hover my li > a it also changes color on my glyphicon. I have listede below my html and what i **tryed** to do in css. But that does only change it **if** i hover the glyphicon and not the a. And **yes** i have also tryed to change it on my a but that dosen't effect my glyphicon.

Html:

```
<li class="pushy-item">
     <a href="#">History 
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt opacityDown pull-right"></span>
     </a>
</li>
```

Css:

```
    ul > li > a > .glyphicon:hover{
    color: orange;
}
```

`

Comment: you do not change the color of icon you CHANGE the icon!

Comment: Ehm. What? @Siddharth

Comment: glyphicons are nothing but part of an big image, we just changed the position of background on hover or some other event, google `css sprite images`

Comment: @Siddharth Got my answere at the bottom.

Comment: @Siddharth What do you mean? It worked and was what i needed? :P

Comment: care to share that code piece/fiddle? i am kinda confused in here

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this:

```
ul > li > a:hover > .glyphicon
```

Comment: Excatly! Thanks Nora

Comment: I dont even understand this. Is that CSS code? What does `>` do?

Comment: From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors): The child combinator (`>`) is placed between two CSS selectors. It matches only those elements matched by the second selector that are the children of elements matched by the first.

Answer (score 0):

```css
div > .glyphicon-heart:hover  {
    color: rgb(102, 102, 101);
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class = "heart">
    <span class = "glyphicon"
        [class.glyphicon-heart] = "isLiked"
        (click) = "onClick()" >
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: You need to describe your solution